# Create roles in Search Guard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have just install plugin Search Guard version Community Edition for testing how to security ELK. Everything is ok now. But when I create Search Guard Roles, I encounter a problem as below. Everything I type in index and Document Type box is not correct. The error notification is the same

Now I user latest version Search Guard with ELK v6.3

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an annoying glitch in the UI. If you want to add an index that does not yet exist, or use wilcdards, make sure to click on the autocomplete fields, and not just navigate to the next input field with e.g. tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same can be achieved using **sgadmin** :-

kindly find typical configuration for two users and two indices Below:-

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
searchguard.roles_mapping_resolution: BACKENDROLES_ONLY
```

**sg_internal_users.yml:**

```
password is :devesh
devesh:
  hash: $2y$12$MRkUaL4Q6WPDbr6rgTVZ1.a8Xm.hps8Q0ONc2Yh6FJTQG0TdgVug2
  roles:
    - onlyfirstindexaccess


# password is :newuser
newuser:
  hash: $2y$12$jaGYV6N7niIpdNyrBMAgh.9.TyIR62jH.masyku3YnsdMoOBzEvI2
  roles:
    - onlysecoundindexaccess
```

**sg_roles.yml:**

```
onlysecoundindexaccess:
  readonly: true
  cluster:
    - CLUSTER_COMPOSITE_OPS_RO
  indices:
    'secoundindex':
      '*':
        - INDICES_ALL

onlyfirstindexaccess:
  readonly: true
  cluster:
    - CLUSTER_COMPOSITE_OPS_RO
  indices:
    'firstindex':
      '*':
        - MANAGE
        - INDEX
        - READ
        - SEARCH
```

role devesh is mapped to indices firstindex and role newuser is mapped to secondindex